# Where's Kevin's archangel?

Tags: supernatural

In the TV series *Supernatural*, when we were first introduced to prophets, we learned they're always protected by an archangel.  These serve to keep the prophet safe from harm.  However, in Season 7, when we were introduced to Kevin Tran, he seems to not have an archangel protecting him.  Some non-archangels show up to take Kevin to the desert to fulfill his destiny, but we never see his archangel.  Those non-archangels meet their demise, but when we next hear from Kevin, he's been fleeing from demons.  This indicates that he's still not protected by an archangel.

Why didn't he get an archangel protecting him?

Comment: My archangel? He keeps following me around, I can't get rid of him...

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. That mean's I didn't have to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Supernatural, there were only ever four archangels named. They are, in order of power (roughly):

1. Michael
2. Lucifer
3. Gabriel
4. Raphael

> The first two are locked in the Cage. Gabriel was (apparently) killed by Lucifer at the end of season 5. And Raphael was smote by Super-Castiel.

We know of no other archangels, and in season 7 it is hinted that none are left. Normal angels step in to protect Kevin Tran.

If the writers wanted to introduce new archangels, it wouldn't contradict Abrahamic mythology. Depending on which you want to read about, there may be as many as 3 or 4 dozen.

Comment: And even if there were more, they could fall under the same umbrella as Raphael

Comment: There is one other archangel i believe, Metatron, though his status is...odd.

Comment: Metatron isn't an archangel. He did bitchslap Crowley, but this isn't anything Castiel couldn't do, especially if he had surprise on his side.

Answer (score 10):

In early Judeo-Christian writings, there are generally a group of seven known archangels:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Archangels

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archangel

In the earliest Christian writings, the seven are noted as: Michael, Gabriel, Raphael, Uriel, Chamuel, Jophiel, and Zadkiel.

> As said earlier, Michael, Gabriel, Raphael, and Lucifer are effectively out of the picture. Uriel is dead. The Angel Joshua, who his the caretaker of The Garden, seems to have powers associated with that of Chamuel.

Jophiel is believed to be the archangel who drove Adam and Eve from the garden and responsible for guarding the Tree of Life, but the name has not surfaced in the show. Both Jophiel and Zadkiel appear to be subservient to Michael, but are still considered to be archangels.

In slightly later Christian writings, a slightly different set of archangels are named: Gabriel, Michael, Raphael, Uriel, Simiel (aka Satan), Oriphiel and Zachariel

In early Jewish writings (which aren't officially recognized by Jewish or Christian traditions), seven also appear: Gabriel, Michael, Raphael, Uriel, Raguel, Remiel and Saraqael.

Roman Catholic tradition recognizes only three archangels: Gabriel, Michael and Raphael. (All other [named angels were officially invalidated in 2002](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/italy/1390845/Vatican-bans-rogue-angels.html), because the book that named them was not officially included in The Bible)

Eastern Orthodox tradition recognizes seven archangels: Gabriel, Michael, Raphael, Uriel, Selaphiel, Jegudiel, and Barachiel. (Eastern Orthodox tradition officially recognizes the book that the Roman Catholic tradition does not).

In Anglican and Episcopal tradition, there are four archangels recognized: Gabriel, Michael Raphael, and Uriel.

Depending on which religious traditions or writings the writers of the show chose to run with, there could potentially be up to seven archangels (or more if the writers chose to recognize all the named archangels that show up in the various religious traditions)

Comment: Quite interesting...  Although [Uriel](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Uriel) (a regular angel) and [Zachariah](http://supernatural.wikia.com/wiki/Zachariah) (a Seraph, an alternate of Zachariel?) have already shown up

Answer (score 2):

John O has said correctly. There are 4 archangels namely Lucifer, Michael,Gabriel and Raphel.

> Micheal is in cage with Lucifer.
>  Gabriel was killed by Lucifer.
>  There is no sign of Raphel after his encounter with Castiel in which he lost. All 4 archangels are gone and that's why normal angels came to protect Kevin Tran.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been open for a while but it is bugging me so I wanted to add this...  It's not a full answer to the original question but should help settle the question of Metatron being mentioned as an archangel or not.

It seems that Metatron's status in Supernatural has changed over time.  He was mentioned as an Archangel in season 8, episode 7 "A Little Slice of Kevin".  In ACT FOUR of this episode, Crowley has Kevin in the abandoned warehouse, has cut off one of Kevin's fingers while trying to make him read the demon tablet, and is sitting there blowing on a red spinwheel.  Sam, Dean & Castiel have arrived and are attempting to fight their way through to save Kevin.

> **INT. WAREHOUSE/FACTORY - DAY**  *(The stone tablet seems to shake in KEVIN's hands.)*
>
> **KEVIN**     *Hold on.  This is different.  It's - it's not text.  It's like a personal note?*
>
> **CROWLEY**   *A personal note from God?*
>
> **KEVIN**     *From... the **archangel**... Metatron.*
>
> **CROWLEY**   *The scribe... and suck-up.  Took down God's word, picked up his cleaning.*
>
> **KEVIN**     *It's like - a farewell note.*
>
> **CROWLEY**   *Go on.*

After this point, the writers seem to have changed their plans for Metatron.  I'm guessing that keeping him as an archangel, considering how they've portrayed archangels as being so powerful, wouldn't have worked well when they set him up as the "villian" later on.  Instead of being a super powerful angel taking over, he was a regular angel who wanted revenge against the archangels who shunned him and the angels who pushed him out of Heaven.

Now he's dead so it doesn't matter but regardless I hope this helps add something to this old discussion...

Comment: Welcome to SFF! This a good first post, nice job adding a quote. Also, I do feel that this does fully answer the question (Q: Where's Kevin's archangel; A: Metatron is his archangel and here is my proof). I can't tell if is the *correct* answer because I am not familiar with the material. Keep up the good work, and maybe swing by our tour page.

Answer (score 0):

At the time, Gabriel and Raphael were dead, and Michael and Lucifer were in the cage. No archangels could have possibly dropped in to keep Kevin safe.

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't really add anything that's not in John O's answer

Answer (score -2):

Metatron is mentioned as being an archangel in Little Slice of Kevin, but in season eight he is shown to have turned off his angel radio as Castiel does many times which is why he doesn't come to aid.

Comment: Metatron himself states that he is not an archangel. On the other hand, he casually bitchslaps Crowley like it wasn't any big deal.

Answer (score -3):

Recent episodes introduce a new Archangel Metatron, heaven's scribe...His status is unknown...

Comment: Could you flesh this out a bit with more detail? Do you know which episode they reference him being an archangel?

Comment: Incorrect, he was never mentioned to be an Archangel, in fact, Season 8 Episode 21 clearly states he was administration (or something like that) before God chose him to be the scribe.

Comment: @Randomman159 The first time we hear of Metratron, Kevin refers to him as Archangel Metratron, meaning it was mistakenly thought he was an Archangel.

Answer (score -4):

Kevin tran is not a prophet. He is able to read the word of god. There may be several prophets, but only one person who can read the word of god.

Metatron is not an archangel

Comment: It was explicitly stated multiple times that Kevin Tran is the current Prophet of the Lord, and that there were many other candidates that could take his place if he died.