# No one caring about the Prophet of the Lord

Tags: supernatural

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where’s Kevin’s archangel?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24535/wheres-kevins-archangel)

In the television series, Supernatural in S04E18, it is established that when a prophet is protected by a lot of angels and if the prophet and a demon are in the same room at a point of time, lot of trouble comes upon the demon. Anyhow, later is Season 07 and 08, we see the prophet being tortured, bullied and what not by many demons especially the king of hell, but no help coming in to save the prophet.

In the latest episode, The King of the Hell cuts a finger of the Prophet.

Why doesn't an angel show up as they did in previous episodes.

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: The question seems to be, "Why doesn't an angel show up..." to save the prophet referred to in that circumstance.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure this is explicitly dealt with in one of the episodes where Kevin is held hostage and auctioned off by Crowley. An angel does show up to try protect him, and angels do occasionally step in and try to take over protection detail at various points. But they are not *archangels* because all of those are gone:

- Lucifer killed Gabriel
- Castiel killed Raphael (the archangel that protected "Chuck")
- Michael and Lucifer are trapped in hell
- Metatron is AWOL.

With all of their top-level angels out of the picture, Heaven is in a state of chaos. This is referenced repeatedly during subsequent seasons, including the civil-war-in-Heaven and the release of the Leviathans, etc.

I doubt there are any angels left that are strong enough to take on the King of Hell. Though they are obviously still *trying* to keep an eye on him, they just aren't up to the task.

(I also suspect this will change as this eighth season progresses, based on the current storyline with Castiel and Heaven.)